# Django - Sort Content From Database by ID

Tags: django, loops, for-loop

I am using Django 1.5.1 and right now I have a table showing content from by database so what I am basically doing is printing the rows from the database to the webpage.

To print each line from the database I am using the following code

```
{% for post in posts %}
Code here where I call on content from database.
{% endfor %}
```

Right now it is printing out the content in ascending ID order but what I want it to do is print in descending ID order. So basically instead of 1 2 3, and I want it go 3 2 1 (if that makes sense).

I believe it would have something to do with that for loop line, but im not sure.

How could I get it to print out in descending order with respect to the ID.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you query the posts do:

```
Post.objects.order_by('-id')
```